# Multiplexer does not support wildcard [MATCH]

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am dash features, MATCH, ALL and ALLSMALLER for creating dynamic dash component and callbacks regarding them.
But I am getting this error.

> @app.callback(
> [
> Output({'type': 'method_title','index': MATCH},'style'),
>
> ```
> ]
> ,
> [
>     Input({'type': 'save_rule_btn_usr','index': MATCH}, 'id'),
>     State({'type': 'payment','index': MATCH}, 'value' ),
>     State({'type': 'payment_method','index': MATCH}, 'value' )
>
>     
> ] )
> ```

**Multiplexer does not support wildcard [MATCH]**

Answer (score 0):

The lack of support of the `MATCH` (and `ALLSMALLER`) wildcard(s) is a known limitation of the  `MultiPlexerTransform`, see the [documentation](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions#know-limitations).

To work around it, you could rewrite the callback to use the `ALL` wildcard. It's a bit less elegant (you'll need to filter the inputs yourself), but it should work.